# Tab character in itext

Tags: java, itext

I have write the code to create the report using itext.For that,i have to add the header
which is like

```
 BSJ                        Economy Report                            Date:31/12/10
```

For that i need to put the tab character(\t) between the above strings.But i can't find out the tab character in itext.I have used "\t" and "\t".This was not working.Please help me to resolve this issue.

Comment: Have you read [this](http://itext-general.2136553.n4.nabble.com/How-to-include-tab-characters-in-a-PDF-td2144044.html)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't one.

Sounds like a job for a 3-column table.  Or perhaps a ColumnText drawing into the same rectangle with three different alignments?

Lots of options.

Comment: Hi Mark,If i make it as 3-column table.How can i add the table as a header in the pdf document?

Comment: Search SO for adding a header to PDF in iText.  This is been answered Many Times here.

Answer (score 0):

to put tab caracter. We do like that

```
p = new Paragraph();

p.setTabSettings(new TabSettings(56f));

p.add(Chunk.TABBING);

p.add(new Chunk("Hello World with tab."));
```

Comment: You can use Paragraph `Paragraph.setIndentationLeft(40f)` instead.

You also can use `cell.setPaddingLeft(40f);` for table cell.